# Issues importing csv data into R where the data contains additional commas

Tags: r, csv

I have a very large data set that for illustrative purposes looks something like the following.

Cust_ID , Sales_Assistant  , Store 
123     , Mary, Worthington, 22 
456     , Jack, Charles    , 42

The real data has many more columns and millions of rows. I'm using the following code to import it into R but it is falling over because one or more of the columns has a comma in the data (see Sales_Assistant above).

```
df <- read.csv("C:/dataextract.csv", header = TRUE , as.is = TRUE , sep = "," , na.strings = "NA" , quote = "" , fill = TRUE , dec = "." , allowEscapes = FALSE , row.names=NULL)
```

Adding row.names=NULL imported all the data but it split the Sales_Assistant column over two columns and threw all the other data out of alignment. If I run the code without this I get an error...

Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

...and the data won't load.

Can you think of a way around this that doesn't involve tackling the data at source, or opening it in a text editor? Is there a solution in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- read.csv("C:/dataextract.csv", skip = 1, header = FALSE)
df_cnames <- read.csv("C:/dataextract.csv", nrow = 1, header = FALSE)

df <- within(df, V2V3 <- paste(V2, V3, sep = ''))
df <- subset(df, select = (c("V1", "V2V3", "V4")))
colnames(df) <- df_cnames
```

It may need some modification depending on the actual source

Comment: I like the way you're going with this and it works up to the point where I run... colnames(df) <- df_cnames. The row with the desired colnames in the df_cnames data frame has a row number 1. The colnames(df) <- df_cnames code then renames all the columns in the target df to 1??

Comment: This issue was related to df_cnames data being factors. The following fixed it... df_cnames <- data.frame(lapply(df_cnames, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: You may alternatively add stringsAsFactors = FALSE as a parameter to read.csv. Or even set it global using options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE). Reading strings as factors is more often confusing then helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, it is a csv file. "Mary, Worthington" is meant to respond to two columns. If you have commas in your values, consider saving the data by using tsv (tab-separated values).

However, if you data has equal amount of commas per row with good alignment in some sense, I would consider ignoring the first row (which is the column names as you read the file) of the data frame and reassigning it proper column names.

For instance, in your case you can replace Sales_Assistant by

```
Sales_Assistant_First_Name, Sales_Assistant_Last_Name
```

which makes perfect sense. Then I could basically do

```
df <- df[-1, ]    
colnames(df) <- c("Cust_ID" , "Sales_Assistant_First_Name" , "Sales_Assistant_Last_Name", "Store")
```

Comment: thanks for contributing. This is a little too manual for the dataset as there are several columns affected by the issue described and I'd rather have a code based solution than manually typing out different col names. :)